# How do I plot ternary phase diagrams using Flory-Huggins solution theory?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-diagram

I have three components, $A,B,C$, with 3 Flory-Huggins exchange parameters: $\chi _{AB}, \chi _{BC}, \chi _{AC}$. I want to create a ternary diagram to see how such a mixture behaves and how phase separation takes place i.e find points on the ternary plot where I will see $(A+B,C), (A+C,B), (B+C,A), (A+B+C), (A,B,C)$, where $I+J$ represents a mixed phase of $I,J$ and a separation by a comma $","$ indicates the third species is in a different phase.

The ternary spinodal condition is:
$$D=\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial \phi _B ^2}\Bigg|_{N,T,\phi_A}\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial \phi _A ^2}\Bigg|_{N,T,\phi _B} - \left( \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial \phi _B \partial \phi _A} \Bigg| _{N,T}\right)^2 = 0$$

My question is, how do I find the regions on the ternary plot indicated above? How do I find the region where two species are mixed while the third one is not?

I am not quite sure what it means when A+B is in a mixed state and when C is not. Does this mean that $\mu _A = \mu _B \neq \mu _C$?

This is basically the figure I want to make [from this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ma00128a005):
[image]

I would appreciate any advice you have for me.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but since it has been more than 6 months, is there any update you can provide us? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Please let us know!